# php print array out in correct order

Tags: php

I have the following array:

```
[answer] => Array
    (
        [0] => A
        [2] => E
    )
```

I run the following code:

```
for ($i = 0; $i < 3; $i++){
   if (!isset(answer[$i]))answer[$i] = "X"; 
}
```

and get the following:

```
[answer] => Array
    (
        [0] => A
        [2] => E
        [1] => X
    )
```

Is there a way to preserve the order so we get:

```
[answer] => Array
    (
        [0] => A
        [1] => X
        [2] => E
    )
```

Comment: Where do you output?

Comment: Maybe https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.ksort.php?

Comment: It is indeed [ksort()](https://3v4l.org/I6WpA). Next time you ask a question please test your code, there are 2 syntax errors in it.

Comment: What are the two errors? The code runs as is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use ksort and it will sort the array in place.

https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.ksort.php

```
$answer =["0" => "A","2" => "E"];    

for ($i = 0; $i < 3; $i++){
   if (!isset($answer[$i]))$answer[$i] = "X"; 
}

ksort($answer);
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the simplest way is to sort array using ksort: https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.ksort.php.

```
$input = [
  0 => 'A',
  2 => 'E'
];
ksort($input);
var_export($input);
```

Or if you don't want to sort for some reason, you can use another array to store data in order you expect:

```
$input = [
  0 => 'A',
  2 => 'E'
];

for($i = 0; $i < 3; $i++){
      $temp[] = isset($input[$i]) ? $arr[$i] : 'X';
}

var_export($temp);
```

Output for two methods (as expected):

```
array (
  0 => 'A',
  1 => 'X',
  2 => 'E',
)
```